# "dev" config overrides "test" config in Quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus, microprofile, eclipse-microprofile-config

In my Quarkus application, I don't want passwords to be versionned by Git.

I don't have any issue with the `prod` profile because I have a config file in `$PWD/config/application.properties`. Fine.

For the `dev` profile, I'm using the `.env` approach which contains properties such as :

```
QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=foo
```

I'm trying to setup tests and I need some separate conf for tests.
So I have the following config in my `src/test/resources/application.properties` :

```
%test.quarkus.datasource.password=bar
```

Unfortunately, **the test value (`bar`) is overriden by the `.env` value (`foo`)** which is supposed to be dedicated to the `dev` profile.

I don't find an elegant way to fix it.

Based on https://quarkus.io/guides/config#overriding-properties-at-runtime I have 5 possible approachs:

1. "using system properties": I'd prefer to have a file for that, so each developer can have its own file and no need to adapt the command line before launch ;
2. "using environment variables": Same reason ;
3. `.env` file: Could work, but I can't specifiy value for `dev` profile only (aka `%dev.[...]`) ;
4. `$PWD/config/application.properties` file: well, this is for dev mode, I don't find it convinient as target is cleared and I have to copy again the `config` folder after each `mvn clean` ;
5. Create my own `ConfigSource` or `ConfigSourceProvider`. I know this one could work, but I prefer to avoid doing specific stuff in my project, and stay with the builtin Quarkus config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found that I was wrong about that :

> 3. `.env` file: Could work, but I can't specifiy value for dev profile only (aka `%dev.[...]`) ;

It is possible to have custom profile values in `.env` file :

```
_DEV_QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=foo
```

As I can prefix the property with `_DEV_[...]`, this value is for `dev` profile only: the `test` property is not overriden anymore.